# How to make a <td> as a new row using external css?

Tags: html, css, html-table, external

I am new to stack overflow and I'm trying to make a mobile webpage from the existing desktop version webpage someone else created. Basically, I have to use same webpage for both mobile and desktop. For this specific page with table, I am trying to change the pattern of table for mobile using external style sheet.I had attached the html skeleton and css with this post. Initially, there is only one row with two  s.  I want to bring ".td2" to new  in next line. I tried a basic table in which I was able to bring down all  converted to tr worked but in this case, second  containing a table is making me hard. I tried all the way I could. I will be helpful if someone help me.

```css
tr{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.lfttbl .td1, .td2{
    display:table-row;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #2b9ed5 !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="out">
    <tr><td>
        <table class="outtbl">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="lfttbl">
                <tr>
                    <td class= td1>
                       <p> hihi hii
                    </td>
                  <td class= td2>
                        <table class = rttbl"">
                          
                          </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't nest tables.  Also don't use tables for layouts.  Try learning about the `<div>` and `span` elements and responsive CSS.

Comment: You can use `display: block;`. E.g: `.td2 { display: block }`

Comment: @DarrenDavies: I am not allowed to change layouts :(

Comment: @NanangMahdaenEl-Agung: Ya I tried that too but no luck. Thank you for replying.

Comment: I've try it and working. The problem is your `<p>hihi hi` is not closed. It should be `<p>hihi hi</p>`

Comment: Actually i kept that paragraph just as an example and i know this code snippet wont work because i want to attach and show all the structures of code and css i am using. I am sorry if i confuses you. The code itself is so vague so i thought of keeping basic skeleton of html.  There is one row with two td for which i have to bring second td to new row. the problem is there is a table in the second td. if it make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of bugs in your code:

1. `<p>` not closed!
2. Using tables for layout.
3. More worse: Using nested tables.

Going ahead with your layout, I was able to make these corrections to make it work in CSS.

```css
tr{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.lfttbl .td1, .td2{
    display:table-row;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #2b9ed5 !important;
}

.td1 {
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table class="out">
    <tr><td>
        <table class="outtbl">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="lfttbl">
                <tr>
                    <td class= td1>
                       <p> hihi hii</p>
                    </td>
                  <td class= td2>
                        <table class = rttbl"">
                          
                          </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Paragraph was just an example I gave. As I mentioned earlier, this is old pre-existing someone else created.

Comment: @Molly That's fine. The answer is the `display: block;`. Try and let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You must close your `<p>hihi hi` and use `display: block;` on the td.
Check this:

```css
tr{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.lfttbl .td1, .td2{
    display:block;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #2b9ed5 !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="out">
    <tr><td>
        <table class="outtbl">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="lfttbl">
                <tr>
                    <td class= td1>
                       <p> hihi hii</p>
                    </td>
                  <td class= td2>
                        <table class = rttbl"">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                          </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wow it works for paragraph in second td but i dont get it why it didn't work for table in second td

Comment: You need to apply the `display: block` to all element that you need. E.g: `table, tr, td { display: block; }`

Comment: Ahh so you mean, basically list all table, tr and  td  (in "lfttbl .td1, .td2{" )which are in right side of the td?

Comment: Emm, i'm not pretty clear about what you looking for. Let me explain, table has `display: table`, tr has `display: table-row` and td has `display: table-cell`. and `display: block` will override the default (UA) style for them. So you choose in which element you want to apply the overrides.

Comment: It worked when i kept css internally but didn't work when i kept same css code externally. Well I am trying to make 3 td of a table row(tr) into  3 individual tr which is done by "display: block" . I am thinking, is it because of "!important" i added in external css. I kept it as i had inline css in my webpage (inline css designed for desktop version webpage, which i cant change. but i have to create or design css for mobile version). so in order to override inline css i had to create an external css with lots of !important. I am sorry if i confuse you. Thanks al for trying to help me out

Comment: Well, if the problem is because inline styles, you really need to override that. The only way to do that is using `!important` or another inline-style using javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I was struggling on. After several trials and errors, I came to know it works in desktop version now but not in mobile devices. I had attached my code and css on which I was working (Initially "edit" and "delete" were in different td). Now I don't know why its not working on mobo device. I know I can't use if else statement in css (either for desktop or for mobile).

```css
#shipIMtd, #shipIMrighttd1, #shipIMrighttd2{display:block;}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0;">
    <link href="mno.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<META Name="Robots" Content="noindex">
</head>
<table id="shipIMmaintbl" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td align="center">
    <table id= "shipIMsubtbl" border="0" width="940">
  <tr>
<td valign="top" align="center" width="80%">
<div id="shipIMmidacdiv"  class="account-mid"><br />
<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table12">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="shipIMshipadtbl" width="735px" style="width:735px;border:solid 1px #D4D6D8;margin-bottom:15px;">
        <tr>
          <td id="shipIMsubtitle" valign="top" style="border-right: solid 1px #E7E4E4;padding:5px;"><span style="font:600 18px verdana;#2972B6"><strong> Addresses</strong></span></td>
    <td height="35" align="left" bgcolor="#F6F4F4" class="padd-top-lt">&nbsp;</td>
<div id="shipIMtitlediv" class="floatright newAddrBtn"><a href="uvx.asp"><input id="shipIMtitlebtn" type="button"  value="+ Add"></a></div>
</div>
</tr>
     
        <tr id="shipIMshipaddtr">
     <td id="shipIMtd" valign="top" style="border-right: solid 1px #E7E4E4;width:200px;padding:15px;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.</p>  
     </td>
     <td id="shipIMrighttd1" align="left" class="padd-15 border-tbt1">
    <table id="shipIMeditship" cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=80><tr><td>
    <form name="editship" action="abc.asp" method="post" />
     <input type="hidden" name="shipID" value="shpid">
     <input id="shipIMeditbtn" type="submit" value="Edit">
     
    </form>
                </td><td id="shipIMrighttd2">
    <form name="deleteship" action="xyz.asp" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="shipID" value="shpid" />
     <input type="hidden" name="asktype" value="firstask">
     <input id="shipIMdelbtn" type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
    </td></tr></table>
     </td>
   </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

.